# Python inner and outer for loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops, for-loop, automation

I first want the code to execute the first loop. When done, I want the code to execute the inner loop, which it does. But when there's is no option to run the inner loop anymore, I want the code to go back to the outer loop, but it doesn't do that.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

```
    def loop_function():

    #Search client
    searchCustomerButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ibSearchPatient"]')
    searchCustomerButton.click()    

    followLoop = range(0, 10)
    for x in followLoop:
        xpath = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00__'
        xpath += str(x)
        xpath += '"]/td[3]'
        
        #Click on cliënt ID
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

        #Click on Zorgtraject
        zorgtrajectButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
        zorgtrajectButton.click()

        followLoop2 = range(0,10)
        for x in followLoop2:
        # begin the inner loop with:
            try:
                # inner loop code here
                xpath2 = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid1_ctl00__'
                xpath2 += str(x)
                xpath2 += '"]/td[2]'

                #Click on Zorgtraject ID
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()

                #Dossier button
                dossierButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span/span')
                dossierButton.click()

                #Dropdown select
                dropdownSelector = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Arrow"]')
                dropdownSelector.click()

                #Prevent not interactable error
                time.sleep(2)

                #Select 50
                selectDropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[4]')
                selectDropdown.click()

                #Check all documents
                tickDossier = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_headerChkboxPrint"]')
                tickDossier.click()

                #Click print
                printButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_btnPrintBehandelverloop"]')
                printButton.click()

                #Click on Zorgtraject ID
                zorgtrajectButton2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
                zorgtrajectButton2.click()

            except NoSuchElementException: # define here what type of exception is thrown when there is no option to run the inner loop
                loop_function()  # call the function once again if you want to run the outer loop again
            
exec(loop_function())
```

Comment: Do you see any exceptions? What is the actual flow when you run this?

Comment: 1. It checks if there's a client.
2. It checks if there's a care traject.
3. It clicks on dossier.
4. It exports all the dossiers.
5. It (should) check if there's another care traject. If so, it should execute step 4 and 5. 
6. When there are no more care trajects/dossiers, it should go back to select a new client and go through the steps again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the whole code into a function like that:

```
def loop_function():
    followLoop = range(0, 10)
    for x in followLoop:
       # outer loop code here
        for x in followLoop2:
           # begin the inner loop with:
           try:
              # inner loop code here
           except NoSuchElementException: # define here what type of exception is thrown when there is no option to run the inner loop
              loop_function()  # call the function once again if you want to run the outer loop again
```

Comment: And whatever part of code you want to run again: wrap it into a function and just simply call it wherever you want to

Comment: Of course, in the inner loop you can use your own logic depending what you need: e.g. if - else conditional etc.

Comment: Hi @maxt026, thanks for your response! Your code worked for me! I ran into another problem however: 'followLoop' does not increment the XPath anymore. Do you happen to know how this can be resolved? I updated the code in the post.

Comment: Nice to know I helped :) can you upvote my answer? I'd like to increase a bit my reputation on StackOF

Comment: Od you want to re-define a variable after call: you can make the function parametrized

Comment: Upvoted! I'm sorry, I don't know how that would increment the variable 'xpath'. Could you maybe elaborate?